# Android Kotlin - FirebaseMessagingService get token?

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is the code:

```
class LatestFirebaseMessagingService : FirebaseMessagingService() {
    override fun onNewToken(token: String) {
        super.onNewToken(token)

        Log.d("pikabo", token)
    }

    override fun onMessageReceived(remoteMessage: RemoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage)
    }
}
```

Manifest:

```
    <service
        android:name=".classes.LatestFirebaseMessagingService"
        android:stopWithTask="false">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT" />
        </intent-filter>
    </service>
```

I didn't get the token even once?!

I guess I initialized it right because

`val reliableIdentifier: String = FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().id`

In activity is working

What am I missing??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The right way to get firebase token is using addOnCompleteListener as below

```
 FirebaseInstanceId.getInstance().instanceId.addOnCompleteListener { task ->
        if (task.isSuccessful)
            print(task.result?.token)
        else
            print(task.exception?.message)
 }
```

[Take a look at the official documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=es-419)

Comment: Thanks! omg the google documentation is misleading and horrendous in general

Comment: @Pikaboo If you found something confusing in the documentation, you should use the "send feedback" link on top right of each page, and describe what the problem is.